# Do I need an IDE for Java in order to learn Java?

Tags: java, macos

I am new with Java and unable to execute the simplest code. Do I need an IDE for that or are there alternatives? I am on MacOS.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable"?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an IDE at the beginning at all. Just a text editor and the Java environment with the dev tools it provides. And IDE is just a convenience thing that will make you more productive and organized later on but can be really overwhelming and distracting at the beginning. Distractions eat away from your time to concentrate on learning the actual thing.

The fact that you are unable to run basic code without an IDE tells me you are not suited for an IDE.

Start with the just your command prompt/terminal (depends on your operating system).

```
javac MyFirstJavaProgram.java
```

is all you need to build your code and then run it using

```
java MyFirstJavaProgram
```

The IDE does the same thing basically but instead you have a button for this and that plus (depending on the project) it uses some arguments for the ´javac`and`java` that you don't really need at the beginning.

Comment: Good point, you need to run basic code without IDE first. IDE only simplify the process of development, not required.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback.  I just want to write Java but I do not know where to write and see the results when I run the code.  Again thanks a lot.

Comment: @John See my edit.

Comment: Could you post something that would actually work? Your class name would not be valid.

Comment: @matt Did the edit with an actual working class name.

Answer (score 0):

Some popular IDE's for Java include Eclipse, IntelliJ and VS Code.

Comment: @John sure thing. Also want to add that if you just want to practice your data structure, algorithms and function writing, you can improve your Java with sites like codesignal.com, hackerrank.com and leetcode.com to name a few.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with what @rbaleksandar has to say but I think that if you can focus really well on the task at hand (writing code) and IDE is worth it because it will assist you in doing that without having to worry about running code and so and so. Only follow this recommendation if you are SURE you can focus on writing code and ignoring the IDE and stop using it if you get any problems with it as it will just waste your time then. If you decide to use an IDE I recommend IntelliJ IDEA but that is up to you.